# Blank image while picking image from gallery

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-gallery

when my app runs for the first time and i try to select the image for user from  gallery , system asks for permission for accessing the photo gallery and when i allow the permission and try to pick the image the (from thumbnails) selected image appears as totally blank (or maybe its  totally black) once i restart the app this issue gets solved by itself any clue  why is this happening ?

when i try to access the gallery for first time  (and allow the permission ) 
this is how my gallery looks like :

totally normal

[image]

when i select any of the images from thumbnail ,
see there's nothing (totally blank)
[image]

and if i select this (blank)image :

[image]

but once i restart the app 
and select any of the images from thumbnail it works fine from now 
[image]

if anybody faced similar scenario before then please let me know

CODE:

```
userImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(ProfileSetting.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

        }else {


            //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
            Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(ProfileSetting.this, GalleryUtil.class);
            gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
            startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);
        }


    }else {



        //Start Activity To Select Image From Gallery
        Intent gallery_Intent = new Intent(ProfileSetting.this, GalleryUtil.class);
        gallery_Intent.putExtra("Switch", 0);
        startActivityForResult(gallery_Intent, GALLERY_ACTIVITY_CODE);

    }


}
});
```